# How to import names that start with a certain prefix from a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm building a GUI in Python.

I want to store the settings for the GUI in a separate module called `settings.py`. This settings module also contains some other variables/classes. But the GUI has settings that start with `L_`. I want to import from `settings.py` all the names that start with `L_`.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Any reason why you don't put the settings into a list/dict/SimpleNamespace/... instead of cluttering them together with other things?

Comment: Doesn't `from setting import *` solves your problem?

Comment: `import settings; print(settings.L_...)` would generally be considered the sanest way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I just thought of that as well, thank you. However, which should I go with? List or dict?

Comment: @Kshitiz no because there are other definitions in `settings.py` as well and I don't want to import them

Comment: Since you want named settings, a ``dict`` or ``SimpleNamespace`` seems adequate. If you want typing support, ``typing.TypedDict`` or ``typing.NamedTuple`` would work as well. You basically have to decide whether you prefer ``gui["L_key"]`` or ``gui.L_attribute`` access.

Answer (score 1):

Although dynamically defining variables is generally considered bad form, this might be an exception, so here's how to do it:

```
import sys

def import_names(module, prefix, namespace=None):
    """ Utility to add names with the given prefix string to given namespace.
        Default namespace is the caller's globals.
    """
    if namespace is None:
        namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # caller's globals

    for name, value in vars(settings).items():
        if name.startswith(prefix):
            print(f'adding {name} -> {value!r}')
            namespace[name] = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import settings
    import_names(settings, 'L_')
```